# Connecting to Azure Active Directory from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to Azure Active Directory from an ASP.NET application. I am following this article by Microsoft to write the code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp#prerequisites

Below are my values I am putting in the application:

```
    <add key="ClientId" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
    <add key="redirectUri" value="https://localhost:5000/" />
```

For my redirect URI, I use `https://localhost:5000/`. This is what I configured in my App registrations in the Azure portal. When I run my application, I get this error:

[image]

When I change the `redirectUri` to `https://localhost:44368/` then I can see the Microsoft login and Microsoft accepts the userId too, but I get an error after inputting my password saying :

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all. You have to check in App Registrations > Manage > Authentication > Redirect URL and see if the URL https://localhost:44368/ is configured there or not. If its configured, you will be able to get the required response for sure.